# library/platform for managing folksonomy?

Tags: python, tags, taxonomy, ontology, folksonomy

I'm building an application that involves significant user and automated tagging of clothing.

The structure generally looks like:

```
[Category Tag]
exclusive=true
values=pants,shirt,shoe,tie,etc
```

So basically any single item will be tagged with 1 or more tags from each "category." A category of tags may define rules around mutual exclusion, etc.

I've got something in place already but since this tagging mechanic has evolved organically within the project, it wasn't well designed for the central role it now plays in our app.

Before I redesign this, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a library or platform (preferably one that easily interoperates with python) that will allow:

- Creating/adding tags and categories
- Adding metadata to a category so as to allow for enforcement of rulesets (mutual exclusion)
- Ideally it would easy to serialize the dataset for client consumption

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you change the question to have more specific criteria?  As it is now, it's a broad 'which library' question.